# REST based Website

Tags: rest, web

I have to create 2 different websites that would use REST api to interact with a single MySQL database.
I know how to create website with forms..etc using PHP.

How would I use REST api for my websites.I searched and found out that there are libraries for android to use REST api but how to do so in case of a website ?

Answer (score 1):

*REST is a architectural pattern, it is not (by itself) an API.  APIs can implement REST.*

Just like any other API out there, you have to get the documentation for the API and then call it from your source.

Depending on what your requirements are, you may be calling it from javascript or from your PHP backend.

REST is an architecture pattern (you can read more about it at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)) which aims to use HTTP verbs like PUT, POST and DELETE to execute commands against *endpoints* which represent a resource.

To use REST, your backend server will send normal HTTP requests to the API service; so in PHP this means using the various curl libraries to send requests.

Responses are generally in json; but they could be in any other format (or even in binary) - check with the API documentation that you have to consume.

Comment: Can I use the same API created for an android app (using Slim framework in PHP) with the PHP code used in my Website ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is interacting with a REST API, then you need a HTTP client, probably cURL (PHP has a cURL lib). After that you have to check whether your API violates the HATEOAS constraint. If not, then it is called hypermedia API. In that case you have to follow hyperlinks provided by the API in the responses. If it violates the constraint, then it is called web API, and you have to build the method, URL, etc... on the client side again, so your client will break easily by any structural changes of the API. Everything else depends on the message format and the semantic annotations the API uses.

If you want to build a REST API, I strongly suggest you to learn more about the topic. First read the [Fielding diessertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) and check some existing solutions like [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) or [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/)+[JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/). Forget the tutorials. Most information available on the web about how to implement a REST API is flawed.

Comment: REST api can be made with Slim library.Right? How to use them in PHP code of websites. I didn't get a lot of jargons you said, could you help me with a bit naive approach ?

Comment: Building a REST API with SLIM and building a REST client are completely different things. Building a REST API is very similar to building a regular webapplication. For the GET requests you send back some data and some links in a hypermedia format. By REST this can be HTML, but we usually use a machine processable media type, for example ATOM+XML, LD+JSON, HAL+JSON, etc... There are many other REST constraints, so it is hard to be short and not using jargons. Do you want to build a client or both client and REST API?

Comment: I want to connect with the MySQL database from my website using PHP code.The database is also accessed by an android app (I was said that it uses a REST api made with SLIM library).Now can I use that API with the PHP code of my website ?? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also I didn't get Client vs API . REST API makes possible communication to a remote server using HTTP and a REST Client is the application which uses that API to interact with the server. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No, that is correct, it is simple client-server architecture. You can use the REST API with your page, you can use cURL to send HTTP messages to it. Everything else is up to the API specification. It can happen for example that your API does not meat with all of the REST constraints, but they still call it REST, etc... Read its documentation.